# Is there any indexing package for Finnish and Estonian?

Tags: indexing, languages

The problem with these languages is that they make words longer by putting things at the end of the words.

I have been reading [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing) but not sure its support for the given languages.

**How can you make the index based for instance on Estonion or Finnish text?**

Comment: The biggest problem I see is in correctly sorting the entries, which is not supported by MakeIndex, but is by Xindy. Can you make some examples about what your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xindy supports both Finnish and Estonian. You didn't provide example, so there is one, assuming that you use utf8 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hello world
\index{jällivaara}
\index{porvoo}
\index{kirjakieltä}
\index{sanota}
\index{vanhaa}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Index words are random words from wikipedia, I have no idea what they mean.

Index can be processed with command:

```
texindy -M lang/finnish/utf8 -L finnish  finnish.idx
```

For Estonian, it would be

```
texindy -M lang/estonian/utf8  -L estonian finnish.idx
```

Correct way would be to call xindy with

```
texindy -C utf8 -L finnish finish.idx
```

option -C means input encoding. But it seems there is a bug and the compilation fails with error message. So you need to directly load the module for encoding with `lang/finnish/utf8`.

As Egreg said, you can alternatively run `texindy` directly from `pdflatex` if you modify

```
\makeindex
```

to

```
\makeindex[options={-M lang/finnish/utf8 -L finnish}]
```

and call

```
pdflatex --shell-escape finnish.tex
```

to call `texindy` automatically.

Comment: You can also write `\makeindex[options={-M lang/finnish/utf8 -L finnish}]` and run `pdflatex` with the option `-shell-escape` enabled; but `imakeidx` should be loaded with the `texindy` option.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Thank you very much! I had problems in generating indexes that takes also the words with endings there.