# How to configure TexStudio editor to use Xindy?

Tags: indexing, glossaries, texstudio, xindy

I am using TexStudio editor for LaTeXing, I want to use Xindy engine though for indexing, in the commands of TexStudio, I found there is a default command for `texdindy` as in the image below. But how to use xindy then? Do I have to use `xindy` explicitly in texstudio or `texindy` will do the job? is there any possibility also to assign a dedicated key for using `xindy` and how to generate an index with that?
I hope the answer would contain a MWE showing the goodies of xindy by using TexStudio editor, with some explanation of how to make sure that `xindy`, and not other default engines like `makeindex`, is doing the sorting and collating job.

**Notes:**

- I am using TexStudio 2.5.2 version
- xindy does not come with MikTeX distribution, you have to install it manually, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex/114397#114397) is a post for that, although I didn't make it myself, that's why I installed TexLive distribution instead, xindy ships already, and you don't need to install perl separately if you are using windows, or even bother yourself with any other stuff.

[image]

Comment: Under “Build” you can change the “Default Index Tool” to `txs:///texindy` after changing the `texindy.exe` command to Xindy. I’m sure, an MWE from the manual or from this site is already available to test it. A short-cut can be assign via “Shortcuts” → “Menus” → “Tools” → “Index” (which uses the index tool selected under “Build”) or → “Commands” → “TexIndy”. If you don’t want to overwrite the “TexIndy” spot, you can always create a “User Command” under “Build”.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, i did that but this error appeared:Process started: xindy.exe
.....<truncated>....imes) -I / --input-markup (supported: latex, omega, xindy) C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:591: command failed with exit code 1: perl.exe c:/texlive/2012/texmf/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl
Process exited with error(s)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, but when I ran the `xelatex -shell-escape <filename.tex>` from command line, i got the index file. so how to configure texstudio to call the shell escape with xelatex?

Comment: In that view in your image, scroo up, there are four lines (LaTeX, PdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX), add `-shell-escape` to the command (just as you’d write it manually).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this can be done in two steps thanks to  Qrrbrbirlbel afterall, in order to call `xindy` for indexing:

1. Set `texindy` as your default `index tool` by going to optioins -> Configure TexStudio -> Build, Note: make sure to tick the show advanced options, as in the picture below:

[image]
 2. You need to use the shell escape for xelatex or pdflatex, I use xelatex compilation engine for the pdf file, go to commands and add the `-shell-escape` as in the picture below:

[image]

Now it's time for Hello World experiment in a MWE, I borrowed one from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104477/is-there-any-indexing-package-for-finnish-and-estonian/104510#104510):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % cannot be used with xelatex
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hello world
\index{j\"allivaara}
\index{porvoo}
\index{kirjakielt\"a}
\index{sanota}
\index{vanhaa}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}` does it automatically. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar, but one should set texindy as a default tool, otherwise glossary won't show up.