# How to configure TexStudio editor to use glossaries package with makeglossaries and xindy or how to configure TexStudio to use arara?

Tags: indexing, glossaries, texstudio

`Xindy` is an efficient indexing tool, it is an external perl-based application that ships readily with TexLive distribution but not with MikTeX, for the latter one you need to install it manually, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex) thread can be of help. For configuration of `xindy` in TexStudio editor, I had success with `imakeidx` package and `texindy` filter using XeLaTeX compilation, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118857/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-xindy) is the thread for that. However, when it comes to the nice `glossaries` package to create glossaries/acronyms/etc, things are getting more complicated. I want to pass the xindy option of `glossaries` package and *configure* TexStudio to use `makeglossaries` for the `xindy` tool, making use of shortcut keys. I found that both `makeglossaries` and `texindy` are listed among commands in this editor, but still how to set all of these things in TexStudio to compile the PDF file with glossary lists is still a puzzle for me. Making glossaries out the command line is not an elegant way to get the job done, while such automation can be configured into the nice TexStudio editor.
In the below MWE, I could only compile PDF but with not glossaries list, I wonder how to do that using the TexStudio editor and not from the command line?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{def1}{name={first definition},description={description1}}
\newglossaryentry{def2}{name={second definition},description={description2}}

\begin{document}
This is \gls{def1} and this is \gls{def2}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update with arara:**
Configuration of TexStudio in Windows:

[image]

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex    
% arara: xelatex   
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{def1}{name={first definition},description={description1}}
\newglossaryentry{def2}{name={second definition},description={description2}}

\begin{document}

This is \gls{def1} and this is \gls{def2}.
\clearpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Now the big araric moment just press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd> (this is in windows and it can be F1, or F2, it depends):
**Result:**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To simplify the compilation and have more control over the compilation steps I recommend the cool tool `arara`. The tool is well explained in the documentation where you can learn also what are arara rules. The main idea is to setup the compilation steps in your root file. This can be achieved by the following syntax

```
% arara: <rule>
```

For `pdflatex` it is simple:

```
% arara: pdflatex
```

For glossaries it is:

```
% arara: makeglossaries
```

and so on.

You can setup TeXStudio for `arara` as follows.

1. Found out the location of the executable `arara`. Normally it is the same path as `pdflatex` is setuped by TeXStudio. If you are using a Unix system you can do

   ```
   which arara
   ```

   which results on my machine to:

   ```
   /usr/texbin/arara
   ```
2. Open TeXStudio and add a new user-command as shown in the image:
   [image]
   The setup is:

   ```
   user0:Arara       /usr/texbin/arara -v -l %
   ```

   After saving you have finished the implementation of `arara`. If you want to use the internal viewer of TeXStudio you should use the following definition:

   ```
   user0:Arara       /usr/texbin/arara -v -l % | txs:///view
   ```
3. To compile with this new user command you can use a short cut or the menu:
    <kbd>Tools</kbd>--><kbd>User</kbd>--<kbd>Arara</kbd>
   [image]
4. If you want to use the menu bar button, you can add `arara` to the custom menu panel.

---

Back to your compilation you can use the following header:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: true }
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }    
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
```

Comment: Can I use it if I would compile with XeLaTeX? and is there any special thing if I am using windows? if so can you please update your nice answer. You made me discover `arara`, and I found that Alt+Shift+F2 has already been assigned after passing arara into TexStudio.

Comment: @doctorate: Using XeLaTeX means to select the rule `xelatex`: `% arara: xelatex`.

Comment: @doctorate: The shortcuts depends on your system. I have no Windows.

Comment: If you use verbose option (`-v`) in TeXstudio on Windows 10, when there is an error (for example an undefined control sequence) Texstudio blocks and the process remains hanging even if you push the red stop button (you have to kill it with Task Manager). With the log option (`-l`) only: `arara -l % | txs:///view | txs:///view-log` it works like a charm!