# Can't create glossary with glossaries package,Perl Strawberry, error: makeglossaries:Need exactly one file argument

Tags: errors, miktex, glossaries, perl

New to Stack Exchange, and using TeX for a week.. Trying to make glossaries work for a larger document, but this even fails with the first example document provided by the glossaries package.. 
I have: 
TeXStudio 2.5.2
MikTeX 2.9, 
Perl Strawberry latest version 32-bit installed and even checked if the PATH was added correctly (after scavanging other answers to posts) (in commandpromt `perl -v` returns the version.. I checked all the packages needed for the `glossaries` package. I added a custom user command to add the `makeglossaries` command available for running. After a first pdfLaTeX compile and run, I get an error when running `makeglossaries`.

The error message I am getting is:

```
Process started: "C:/LaTeX/scripts/glossaries/makeglossaries.bat"
makeglossaries: Need exactly one file argument. Use `makeglossaries --help' for help.
Process exited with error(s)
```

Please help me solve this, I've looked everywhere and long but nothing can be found on this error. The glossary is not created in the pdf, but the first run does create the 1 page document correctly.

The `.tex` is `minimalgls.tex` (provided by package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{glossaries} % acronym will go in main glossary
 %\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % make a separate list of acronyms
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
description={a sample entry}}

\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey=cas,\glslongpluralkey=contrived
acronyms]{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}
A \gls{sample} entry and \gls{aca}. Second use: \gls{aca}.

Plurals: \glspl{sample}. Reset acronym\glsreset{aca}.
First use: \glspl{aca}. Second use: \glspl{aca}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the edits @moewe, how do I create the grey boxes for subsequent questions etc?

Comment: Have a look at [Markdown help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) or at the changed code of your question.

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem with the way that TeXstudio is calling `makeglossaries`. I don't use TeXstudio, but try [How to configure texstudio to use glossaries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118890/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-glossaries-package-with-makeglossaries). How did you add the custom command?

Comment: @Nicola Talbot I have added a user command (options->configure TeXstudio-> tab Build) where you can enter a command by typing a name and a path.. I have tried "C:/LaTeX/miktex/bin/x64/makeglossaries.exe" which is where I found the .exe file, but as the manual said to load the .bat file, I have also tried "C:/LaTeX/scripts/glossaries/makeglossaries.bat".. Both return me the same error message.

Comment: @RoelandVisser Did you add ` %` (space followed by percent sign) after the path? (I don't know if the percent sign needs to be in double-quotes. It may need it if you have spaces in your path names.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks for looking at it, I did not have the ` %` (space percentsign) after the path. I added it but in both cases (`.bat` and `.exe`) I not get the following error message: `Error: Could not start the command: "C:/LaTeX/miktex/bin/x64/makeglossaries.exe "minimalgls""`. It has now found the right file but can't execute?

Comment: I just tried running through the commandpromt, see if other messages would arise.. after a `latex myDoc` (using the full path for the minimalgls.tex file) I tried `makeglossaries myDoc` and got the following return:
****Call to makeindex failed****
Possible cause of problem: Style name indicates makeindex, but may be in xindy format. Remember to use \setStyleFile to specify the name of the style file rather than redefining \istfilename explicitly. Check 'full path\minimalgls.glg' for details` 
any ideas?

Comment: So, dont know if Im making progress or not.. haha.. I edited the path name to go without double '' in front an aft (so only `C:/LaTeX/miktex/bin/x64/makeglossaries.exe %` is left and then the error I get is `'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` (double checked the PATH cariable and perl responds correctly in commandprompts when executing `perl -v`..

Comment: @RoelandVisser I didn't create the `.exe` file, just the `.bat` file (I assume the `.exe` file was created by the MikTeX maintainers) but it sounds a bit weird that you can run perl from the command prompt but `makeglossaries` can't find it. I don't use Windows, so I can't give much more advice, except maybe to use the `.bat` file and edit it so that it contains the full path to `perl.exe`

Comment: By now I have tried TexMaker as the editor, added the custom command for `makeglossaries` and built the `.tex` file a couple of times as PDF and with the `makeglossaries` command in the Terminal (-> Tools -> Open Terminal) of TexWorks, which worked.. Still can not trace the problem in TeXStudio.. Thanks for the help anyways... (On my mac the glossaries package worked in 5 minutes, so indeed using windows huh?...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with TeXstudio on Windows and did not find out to solve it. I finally download [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) and follow the step describe in the [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Example_for_use_in_windows_with_texmaker).

ie:

```
In Texmaker, go to User -> User Commands -> Edit User Commands.
Chose command 1
Menuitem = makeglossaries
Command = makeglossaries %
Now push Alt+Shift+F1 and then ->F1
```

You have to download and install Xindy which have Perl included (Perl is necessary to run the makeglossaries script).

Edit: The same solution could be used with TexStudio using the following instruction:

```
option -> configure TeXstudio ...
in Build add an User Command and fill it as the image bellow.
Now push Alt+Shift+F1 (or Tools -> User -> makeglossaries)
```

[image]

Comment: Xindy could be find on http://www.fys.ku.dk/~tlinnet/xindy-win.exe

Comment: Read [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71167), please!

Comment: I was just trying to help, but do you mean that this method does not work?

Comment: Your method should be better, sure ... but is complicated. We are just different users and I just want it to work. the method I used is working and solve my problem in a few minutes.

Comment: Your answer is wrong related to the question, but my point was simply, that you recommend a installation of absolutely obsolete versions. Read the answers of linked questions and also the updated Wiki entry. (Oh sorry deleted and rewritten while you wrote your own comment.)