# Deleting ps automatically

Tags: texstudio, workflow

While using the pdf latex chain, how can one delete the *.ps file automatically right after the pdf has been created? *.ps files can be big (~100 MB). Hence, this question.

Comment: I use pdftex, which doesn't create a .ps file.  In general, the same program you used to make the chain may have an option to delete the .ps file afterwards.

Comment: If you *have* to follow the DVI > PS > PDF chain, perhaps using xelatex might be of help to compile directly to PDF.

Comment: Assuming `latex` -> `dvips` - > `ps2pdf`, it's down to the script you use for the build to do the deletion. We'll need more detail about how you do things.

Comment: Presumably this question should not be tagged pdftex, as there are no ps files in that case

Comment: Some editors will do this for you or can be configured to do it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You _can_ edit the tags of questions. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder yes but tag and wording didn't match but I wasn't sure which should change.

Comment: The editor I use is TexStudio 2.6.6.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to compile with `arara` instead of the usual build chain in TeXstudio. `arara` is a compilation tool where you describe which steps should be part of the compilation sequence in comments placed at the top of the file. A description of setting up `arara` in TeXstudio can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118899/586

A minimal example is

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf
% arara: clean: { files: [ test.dvi, test.ps ] }

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

If this is saved in `test.tex`, then running `arara test.tex` will compile the sequence `latex` - `dvips` - `ps2pdf`, and then remove the `test.dvi` and `test.ps` files. Note that in `%arara: ps2pdf` the `ps2pdf` part is *not* the name of a binary, it is the name of a *rule*, which is defined by `arara`. As such, you can't just put the name of any program here.

Sample terminal output:

```bsh
testdir$ ls
test.tex
testdir$ arara test.tex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running LaTeX... SUCCESS
Running DVIPS... SUCCESS
Running PS2PDF... SUCCESS
Running CleaningTool... SUCCESS
Running CleaningTool... SUCCESS
testdir$ ls
test.aux  test.log  test.pdf  test.tex
testdir$
```