# acronym list won't print

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm an IT student who's writing a thesis. IT makes use of a lot of acronyms and so I would like to show an acronym list. For that I made use of the `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}` package. I've defined my acronyms, made my glossary and asked to print it out but nothing shows. I am however able to use the `\acrshort{}`, `\acrlong{}` and `\acrfull{}` commands to reference the acronyms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{rpa}{RPA}{Robotic Process Automation}
\newacronym{ai}{AI}{Artificiële Inteliggentie}
\newacronym{ml}{ML}{Machine Learning}
\newacronym{ipa}{IPA}{Intelligent Process Automation}
\newacronym{bpa}{BPA}{Business Process Automation}
\newacronym{hr}{HR}{Human Resources}
\newacronym{bpm}{BPM}{Business Process Management}
\newacronym{ocr}{OCR}{Optical Character Recognition}
\newacronym{nlp}{NLP}{Natural Language Processing}
\newacronym{nlg}{NLG}{Natural Language Generation}
\newacronym{cmp}{CMP}{Cognitive Modeling Platform}
\newacronym{idr}{IDR}{Intelligent Digital Robots}
\newacronym{mvp}{MVP}{Minimum Viable Product}
\newacronym{api}{API}{Application Programming Interface}

\begin{document}
\inserttitlepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\printacronyms
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

%example piece of text (in dutch)
\acrshort{rpa} kan gecombineerd worden samen met \acrfull{ai} om zo langere en moeilijkere taken op zich te nemen. Hierdoor worden ze door sommigen beschreven als zelf-verbeterende digitale werkkrachten. Enkele velden waarbinnen \acrshort{rpa} kan gecombineerd worden met \acrshort{ai} zijn \acrfull{ocr} en \acrfull{nlg}. \autocite{everythingRPA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, `makeglossaries`, LaTeX on your file? (Note that the code you shared so far is not a complete example document and can not be compiled directly. It is missing a `\documenctlass` and does not actually use any of the acronyms. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.)

Comment: @moewe the document class that I have to use is a custom one from school, there is no way that I can share this one and what do you mean by run makeglossaries? isn't adding the command enough?

Comment: If the document class is not available publicly, use a standard class like `article`, `report` or `book`. You need to run `makeglossaries` on your document just like you run LaTeX or BibTeX. On the command line you'd just say `makeglossaries docname`, but if you are using an editor, you may have to configure it for `makeglossaries`.

Comment: Possibly interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118890/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1226/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312846/35864

Comment: @moewe the makeglossaries command in iterm did it all! thanks a lot my man! btw the generated files, do they need to be pushed to github or should the others generate them themselves?

Comment: In general it is enough (and better) not to distribute the temporary files. The `.tex` and `.bib` files are normally enough.

Comment: okay! can you write out the response of using the terminal? that way I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document must be compiled with `makeglossaries` for the list of acronyms to show.

So the compilation cycle contains at least LaTeX, `makeglossaries`, LaTeX (where LaTeX is your favourite LaTeX flavour: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...).

If you compile from the command line, that comes down to

```
pdflatex <document name>
makeglossaries <document name>
pdflatex <document name>
```

Though more programs may be involved (the code in the question contains `\autocite`, which suggests Biber might be involved), so you may well have to run

```
pdflatex <document name>
biber <document name>
makeglossaries <document name>
pdflatex <document name>
pdflatex <document name>
```

or more. Usually there should be hints in the `.log` if you need to run additional programs.

If you are using an editor, it should be possible to configure `makeglossaries` as a helper tool.

See also [How to configure TexStudio editor to use glossaries package with makeglossaries and xindy or how to configure TexStudio to use arara?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118890/35864), [How to make Latexmk use makeglossaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1226/35864), [Setting up arara user command in TeXstudio on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312846/35864).