# Indexing/glossaries problem

Tags: xetex, texstudio, glossaries

I am compiling a document with glossaries, but it does not work because xindy is not found.

I get the error:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
%\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{def1}{name={first definition},description={description1}}
\newglossaryentry{def2}{name={second definition},description={description2}}

\begin{document}
This is \gls{def1} and this is \gls{def2}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}  

    ***Call to xindy failed***

Check 'texstudio_lCtsPG.glg' for details
sh: 1: xindy: not found
```

(there is no file `texstudio_ICtsPG.cls`, the logfile says).
I am on a ubuntu mate 20.04 system with Texstudio 2.12.22.

`arara` is on `/usr/bin/arara` and I have thus configured Texstudio as follows (using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118890/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-glossaries-package-with-makeglossaries) this post on tex.stackexchange):

[image]

I have also tried to add `\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}` and putting `txs:///texindy` in the Default Index Tool in the Build tab of the Texstudio configuration, but get the same error. Strangely enough, I have an identical setup on another Xubuntu laptop, where it just works.

How do I print glossaries?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that xindy was included in the 1 GB tex live installation. Not so. `sudo apt install xindy` solved the problem.