# TexStudio with arara; cannot find extractbb

Tags: texstudio, xindy, arara, glossary

With some help from the [prior question TexStudio and arara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118890/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-glossaries-package-with-makeglossaries), I was able to get started with arara inside TexStudio (Yay!). But while running a Xelatex compilation (the 2nd example code in the URL just noted), I got this error message (it did not finish compiling):

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.s
ty
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
! I can't find file `"|extractbb --version"'.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.72     \l__sys_internal_tl
                            
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
runpopen command not allowed: extractbb
```

`extractbb` does exist and (on my machine) it is at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/extractbb`

Just a guess: Is it possible that this is not so much a problem with the path (`` 'I can't find file `"|extractbb --version' ``), but perhaps with shell permission instead (`runpopen command not allowed : extractbb`)??? Any suggestions on how to fix would be appreciated!

------edit, follow David Carlisle's comment regards texmf.cfg-----

My only customizations for my "personal" texmf.cfg is the addition of

```
shell_escape_commands = pagelayoutapi
```

whereas the ***un-altered,*** "general" texmf.cfg at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` indicates that

```
% The default is true, because we already avoid adding the standard
% extension(s) in the usual cases.  E.g., babel.sty will only look for
% babel.sty, not babel.sty.tex, regardless of this setting.
try_std_extension_first = t

% Enable system commands via \write18{...}.  When enabled fully (set to
% t), obviously insecure.  When enabled partially (set to p), only the
% commands listed in shell_escape_commands are allowed.  Although this
% is not fully secure either, it is much better, and so useful that we
% enable it for everything but bare tex.
shell_escape = p

% No spaces in this command list.
% 
% The programs listed here are as safe as any we know: they either do
% not write any output files, respect openout_any, or have hard-coded
% restrictions similar to or higher than openout_any=p.  They also have
% no features to invoke arbitrary other programs, and no known
% exploitable bugs.  All to the best of our knowledge.  They also have
% practical use for being called from TeX.
% 
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
```

EDIT--response to egreg's answer
I looked again at`/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf` because, although egreg's changes did in fact resolve the problem, the instructions (provided as comments within the file) are contrary, they indicate that you should ONLY put the changes into that file, NOT all of the original lines present at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`:

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, *NOT A COPY OF THE WHOLE THING!* [caps added here for emphasis--Birdman]
%
```

I am continuing this conversation because I'd like to know whether I've somehow misinterpreted this admonition (--> to not copy the whole thing), or whether those instructional comments are themselves faulty.

Comment: by default `extractbb` is allowed by restricted shell escape, and restricted shell escape is the default mode, so it should work unless you use `pdflatex --no-shell-escape`  but you can change those defaults in `texmf.cnf`  so it depends...

Comment: David--thanks, I added some excerpts from the two texmf.cnf files on my platform. If you could comment, please do.

Comment: all looks normal, `p` and allowing `extractbb` it should work...

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't work (there have been no changes). Extractbb is in the path, whether I search with user or with Root privileges. Any suggestions now? It could be some sort of path issues, because I cannot find 'inkscape' either (when I run 'pagelayout.cls)

Comment: can you type `extractbb --version` on the command line  it should report This is extractbb Version 20220710

Copyright (C) 2008-2023 by Jin-Hwan Cho and Matthias Franz

This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Comment: Yes, but it says 2008-2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely your modification's fault. With

```
shell_escape_commands = pagelayoutapi
```

you are allowing *only* the application `pagelayoutapi` in the restricted shell-escape. If you try

```
kpsewhich --var-value shell_escape_commands
```

from the command line, you should just see

```
pagelayoutapi
```

(just tried out on my machine).

You need to copy the whole list and append to it, when modifying the upper level `texmf.cnf` file:

```
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
pagelayoutapi,\
```

##### How does reading `texmf.cnf` work?

There are usually two `texmf.cnf` files in the TeX tree. One is at the top level, the other one is in `texmf-dist`. The output of

```
kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf
```

on my machine is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

There may be more of these files, but the essential thing to know is that they're read in the order shown by `kpsewhich -a`.

Values of variables that are set in a file are **not** overridden by later files. There is a recommendation in the “main” (but last read) file, namely

```
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, *NOT A COPY OF THE WHOLE THING!* [caps added here for emphasis--Birdman]
```

The “NOT A COPY OF THE WHOLE THING” refers to not adding every variable, but only those you need to change the value of. If you add everything, initialization would be slower, because many values would need to be read and discarded.

If you say in the top level `texmf.cnf` file

```
shell_escape_commands =
```

no external program is allowed in the restricted shell. The variables are not set incrementally: later lines starting with that value are ignored.

Comment: oops I only noticed the unchanged list not that the OP had over-ridden it

Comment: Bingo! Problem solved! Now, to solve that issue about "inkscape not installed" in another of my other questions

Comment: Regards changes to texmf.cnf, please see the EDIT in the original post----the instructions provided (as comments) in the texmf.cnf file are confusing!

Comment: @Birdman I added some comments, please ask again if something's not clear.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now; ```shell_layout command = pagelayoutapi``` of ```/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf``` isn't appended as a single item to that long list of items allowed by ```shell_escape command = ...``` found in the file ```/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf```. Rather, because the 'top level' is read first, it sets ```shell_escape command =...``` to that singular actionf ```pagelayoutapi``` and that isn't overwritten by the subsequent reading of ```/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf```

Comment: This of course relies on an understanding of 1) sequence (PRIORity in the strict sense) and 2) the valuation assigned by the programmer ("priority", sensu lato), for which I thank you [egreg] for the valuable explanation!