# How can I change the default order between letters of an alphabet?

Tags: indexing, languages, arabic, alphabet, persian

I'm writing a book in Persian. In its index there is a problem. Words are using Arabic order! So it causes a problem as in Arabic language they don't have four letters 'پ p (in pen)', 'چ ch (in cheese)', 'گ g (in gas)' and 'ژ zh or s (in usual)'. So these 4 letters are deleted from their main places and these are appeared after all letters but it's wrong, for example 'پ p' should be after 'ب b' and before 'ت t'.
I would to see can I define order between letters of an alphabet myself. So I'm not only seeking a solution for the above problem and my question is the generalized form of it (the general case may be useful sometimes).

As some may need an example I wrote one (this is just an example).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[next]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=1.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\author{A.H. SadeghiManesh}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
نمونه
\index{بالارونده}
\index{پائین‌رونده}
\index{تعمیم قضیه}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The result is as the image. but the third word should be between two others and not the last one!
 [image]

Comment: Are you using `xindy`? An MWE would really help here. Please give three example index entries and mark the one, which is set to the wrong place. I do not speak Persian and do not want to set up this problem for you. Information about your index packages and the language packages as well as the documentclass are mandatory here. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Is the example I added what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the output, I guess you use `xelatex file.tex`, then `makeindex file.idx`, and finally `xelatex file.tex` again. This won’t work, as `makeindex` isn’t so language-aware.

You can use [`xindy`](http://www.xindy.org/) ([xindy](/questions/tagged/xindy)) for the middle step instead, with the support for Persian being provided by [`xindy-persian`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/xindy/contrib/xindy-persian). The easiest way would be downloading `xindy-persian` to the sub-directory below the one your `.tex` file is in, and using `texindy -M xindy-persian/variant1-utf8-test.xdy file.idx` (you can also use `variant2`, which is slightly different (see [`README`](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/indexing/xindy/contrib/xindy-persian/README)), or change `-test` with `-lang`).

Here is the output; I hope this is what you were expecting.

[image: Persian indexing using <code>xindy</code>]

Comment: Yes it corrected the problem of Persian index and I downloaded xindy-persian but I couldn't understand how to use it.

Comment: * Step 1: download and unzip [this file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/xindy/contrib/xindy-persian.zip) into the same directory you’ve placed your `.tex` file in.
* Step 2: compile your file using XeLaTeX: `xelatex file.tex`.
* Step 3: process the index using `xindy`: `texindy -M xindy-persian/variant1-utf8-test.xdy file.idx`.
* Step 4: recompile it with the processed index: `xelatex file.tex`.

Of course you can place `xindy-persian` in other directories. Placing it under the same directory of the `.tex` files is simple, yet not flexible (say, when you want to use it for several projects).

Comment: It seems one cannot break lines in comments here. Meh…

Comment: Sorry to ask again, I can't understand how to process the index using xindy: texindy -M xindy-persian/variant1-utf8-test.xdy file.idx, I'm using TeXstudio and I just know for index I should use F12 ~_~ really sorry, may you describe this part?

Comment: That’s OK ☺. The process I wrote is to be done via command line. If you use TeXstudio, maybe this SE QA will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118857/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-xindy.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Thank you so much, the link was absolutely useful. ^_^ Now the index is OK. (I'm using windows)

Comment: I’m happy to hear that ☺.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine I could only get this to work by specifying the full location of the persian `xdy` file: `texindy -M "D:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\xindy\modules\lang\persian\variant1-utf8-test.xdy" test.idx`